# What do these Eclipse PyDev template variables do? ('next_class_or_method', 'prev_class_or_method')

Tags: eclipse, templates, pydev

I'm customizing some code templates for PyDev (Eclipse). Inside the `Edit Template` dialog, which can be found at:

```
Preferences => PyDev => Editor => Templates => {select_a_template} => Edit => Insert Variable
```

..there are a number of built-in variables. Most of them make sense, but there are 2 that don't, namely: `${next_class_or_method}` and `${prev_class_or_method}`

What does that even mean in (either of) the context(s) of Eclipse Templates??

How would one go about using such a thing in a code template?

What would be **even better**, would be if there were some file in PyDev that could be altered to allow me to make my own "built-ins".

Does anyone out there know of these things?

Answer (score 0):

Those give you the next declared class or the next declared method.

For an example that uses the ${next_class_or_method}, take a look at: http://pydev.blogspot.com.br/2011/06/overrideimplements-templates-on-pydev.html

For the previous one, I don't have an example (it's a mix of the ${current_class} and ${current_method} -- which is used on the 'super' templates, but it won't distinguish if you have a class or a method before it).